# Новая строка в DataGrid из TextBox с новыми данными

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid, textbox

Суть вопроса: Подключена база данных DataBase.mdf.
Как добавить из TextBox данные допустим число 1 в DataGrid, так чтобы появилась новая строка. Допустим записал число 1, и с помощью Button это число вставляется в ячейку и снизу появляется новая строка, для следующего добавления нового числа из этого же TextBox.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
namespace Пробник
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.tableBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.database1DataSet);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "database1DataSet.Table". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
            this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Table);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В обработчике кнопки `button1`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Обращаемся к таблице (DataTable), которая отображается 
    // в элементе `DataGridView` создаем новую строку и заполняем
    // ее данными из элементов `TextBox`.
    var row = database1DataSet.Table.NewRow();
    row[0] = textBox0.Text;
    row[1] = textBox1.Text;
    row[2] = textBox2.Text;
    row[3] = textBox3.Text;

    // Добавляем созданную строку в коллекцию строк таблицы.
    database1DataSet.Table.Rows.Add(row);

    // Сохраняем изменения.
    database1DataSet.Table.AcceptChanges();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ, буду завтра пробовать, а то всю голову сломал!!!